# Cannot display all the element of my array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, display

I've some trouble with my array. Well, I want to sort an array of 5 integer elements. However, when I display them, it displays only the last element and its value is not the one I'm expecting to have after sorting.

Hence, could help me to troubleshoot this problem, please?

N.B: Here is my code

main.h

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   main.h
 * Author: Yacin
 *
 * Created on 19 septembre 2021, 12:49
 */

#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

int sommeTableau(int tab[], int taille);
int moyenneTableau(int tab[], int taille);
int * copieTableau(int tab1[], int tab2[], int taille);
int * valMaxTableau(int tab[], int taille, int valMax);
int * ordonnerTableau(int tab[], int taille);


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif




#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* MAIN_H */
```

main.c - ordonnerTableau function :

```
int * ordonnerTableau(int tab[], int taille){
    int tmp;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < taille; i++){
        int j = 0;
        while(tab[j] > tab[j+1]){
            tmp = tab[j];
            tab[j] = tab[j+1];
            tab[j+1] = tmp;
            j++;
        }   
    }
    return tab;
}
```

main.c - main function :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int dtab[5] = {12, 9, 2, 1, 0};

printf("Avant :\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        printf("tab[%d]=%d\n",k , dtab[k]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Après :\n");    
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("tab[%d]=%d \n",j ,*(ordonnerTableau(dtab, 5) + j));
    }
```

output :

```
Avant :
tab[0]=12
tab[1]=9
tab[2]=2
tab[3]=1
tab[4]=0

Après :
tab[4]=0
```

Expected output :

```
dtab[5] = {0,1,2,9,12}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

YT

Comment: `while(tab[j] > tab[j+1])` accesses outside the array.  Needs a limit so `j+1 < taille`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should not hardcode the size of the array using `5`.  Instead, you should use `sizeof(dtab)/sizeof(dtab[0])`.
2. Inside `ordonnerTableau` you have `taille=5` but you try to fetch `tab` on these posisions: `tab[j] > tab[j+1]` without being sure `j` and `j+1` are less than 5.

Comment: It works, ty bros !!! :-)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, it's done